# momentjs: check if string is a date in a specific format

Tags: angular, momentjs

I receive a number of strings and if they are dates, I want to format them.

I am using moment.js to check if a string is a date:

Only strings with this format should return true: `2011-03-02T11:02:00+03:00`

However, currently, also this is deemed a valid date: `034932` or this: `279565`.

My code:

```
const date = new Date(dateString);
return moment(date, moment.ISO_8601, true).isValid();
```

How do I check this with momentjs?

I looked at the documentation but I haven't found any format definition that explicitly contains the time zone offset.

Comment: To mark only strings in this particular format as valid it's probably best to write yourself a checking function that works with substring.

Comment: Hmm, but I see that `034932` is considered as invalid. How did you test that? Or which momentjs version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `new Date(dateString)` if you want to check string format using momentjs.
Your code give misleading result because you are parsing your input using native JavaScrpt Date. You have to use [`moment(`**`String`**`, String, Boolean)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) (so first parameter should a string, not a Javacript Date).

Working example:

```js
const isStringValidDate = (dateString) => moment(dateString, moment.ISO_8601, true).isValid();
["034932", "279565", "2011-03-02T11:02:00+03:00"].forEach((val) => console.log(val, isStringValidDate(val)))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a format constructed using the moment object and then use **isValid()** to see if its a valid format .

```js
var dates = ["034932", "279565", "2011-03-02T11:02:00+03:00"];
for (const val of dates) {
  let utc = moment(val, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ", true);
  let isUTC = utc.isValid();
  console.log(isUTC, val);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```